# How to determine if Make target is a PHONY?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a make target that depends on a variable, which contains both PHONY and real targets.

This target needs to depend only on the real targets in the variable.

How can I test a variable to determine if it is a PHONY or not, so I can filter them out?

(I can test for a file's existence inside the recipe, but I don't want my target to be triggered by execution of any of the PHONY targets.)

Thanks!

Comment: `target: $(filter-out $(list_of_phony_targets),$(variable_with_targets))`

Comment: Every phony target appears in a line that begins with `.PHONY:` and instead of filtering them out of the variable, I suggest you use a variable which never contains them to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I have no control over the variable.  I am receiving it from another Make context that I do not control.  Also, I do not have a list of PHONY targets.  If I did, it would be easy.

I'd like to avoid grepping or parsing Makefiles to find PHONY targets.  Make parsers are tricky business.  ;)

I was hoping Make provides a list of PHONY targets or provides some test/function to distinguish between PHONY and real targets.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it, but I would strongly recommend against it. First of, phony targets can be also file targets. And there is no way to tell a phony file target from a non-phony file target.
It looks like the question implies that the phony targets the author wants to ignore are all non-file targets. In this case see the example below.

```
.PHONY: phony_target .FORCE
.FORCE:

ALL_TARGETS = phony_target file_target undetermined_target

-include detect_phony.inc

all: final_target
    # All done

final_target: $(REAL_TARGETS)
    # create $@ triggered by $?
    @touch $@

ifeq (,$(MAKE_RESTARTS))
# Generate the list of real file targets in make include file
detect_phony.inc: .FORCE
    @echo 'REAL_TARGETS = ' `ls $(ALL_TARGETS) 2>/dev/null` > $@ |:
endif

file_target:
    touch $@

undetermined_target phony_target:
    # process $@

clean:
    rm -f file_target final_target
```

Here are the test results:

```
$make clean
rm -f file_target final_target
$ make
# create final_target triggered by 
# All done
$ touch file_target 
$ make
# create final_target triggered by file_target
# All done
$ make
# All done
```

As you can see it only triggers the final target when the file target is updated.

Before you criticize - Here are the flaws of this implementation:

1. make is always called twice, updating the generated detect_phony.inc include file at every run
2. if detect_phony.inc gets corrupted somehow, make execution will be locked by syntax errors, until you manually delete it.
3. it can't handle phony file targets as I mentioned before
4. if another generated include is added in this makefile that requires another restart before detect_phony.inc this functionality will break.

So it this method is hacky and has several gotchas. I would not use it in production environment. I would insist on changing the top level Makefile first.